# Will declaring as pointer with a function that returns a pointer cause a chain of two pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If I declare a pointer with a function that returns a pointer, will the pointer I declared be identical to the pointer the function returns, or will it be a pointer to the pointer that the function returns?

Example:

```
typedef struct foo{
  int n;
} foo;

// this function returns a pointer to a structure foo
foo* returnPointer(){
  foo* tmp = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  tmp->n = 1;
  return tmp;
}

// if I do this, will abc be a pointer to a foo structure (the desired effect)
// or will it be a pointer to another pointer to a foo structure?
foo* abc = returnPointer();
```

Comment: In your case the program will just behave an undefined way because you dereference a pointer that hasn’t been initialized.

Comment: A function returns whatever you tell it to return. If you tell it to return a pointer, it returns that pointer. Why would it return a pointer to the pointer instead?

Comment: @Barmar My assumption was that because the function is already returning a pointer, and when I declare the variable I declare it as a pointer, it might become a chain of pointers. Guess I was wrong

Comment: @phaazon thanks for pointing that out, thankfully that mistake was only made here on SO in my example. I have edited it with corrections

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest The general rule is that you have to return the same type as you declare. If you try to return a *different* type, it may perform a conversion (e.g. `float` could be converted to `int` or vice versa). But if you return the declared type, there's no reason to convert to a different type or value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abc will be what you declare it to be. A pointer to a foo struct. The function also returns a foo * (pointer to a foo struct). So there is type agreement.

edit: Also as @phaazon stated, the function has mistakes (malloc is needed).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare:

```
foo* tmp;
```

You are creating just a pointer to a struct, not the struct itself. You should start creating the struct and then set the pointer to it, like this:

```
foo stFoo;    // create the struct
foo *tmp;     // create the pointer
tmp = &stFoo; // pointer receives the struct address
```

But be aware that if you declare stFoo as local variable inside the returnPointer function, it won't exist anymore after returning form this function. To avoid that, you may declare stFoo as a global variable.